# Stuck at "waiting to connect" during product activation on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, windows-activation

I recently did a clean install of Windows 8. The product key was accepted on installation but when I start my computer it keeps telling me to "Activate Windows". I re-entered the key and it has been stuck on the *Waiting to connect* message ever since. I turned of Windows Firewall and it still will not let me connect.

Answer (score 2):

If you've confirmed you have working Internet on that machine then there's a couple alternative ways to fire off the Activation that may work a little better.

So stop it from trying its current activation, and then attempt one of these methods:

Option 1:

- From the desktop, right-click the start button area at the bottom left corner (or hit Win+X).
- Click "Control Panel" -> System and Security -> Action Center -> Windows Activation.

Option 2:

- Open a Command Prompt 'as administrator'.
- Type `slmgr /ato`, and hit enter.